# SQL subquery returned more than 1 result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query, when I check if Filters are NULL then I Select all, but if they are not null I select only objects that have those filters. The query is as follows.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [PointOfInterest]
WHERE [PointOfInterest].[Id] IN (CASE
                                    WHEN @filters IS NULL THEN [PointOfInterest].[Id]
                                    WHEN @filters IS NOT NULL THEN (SELECT DISTINCT [PointOfInterestIcon].[PointOfInterestId]
                                            FROM  [PointOfInterestIcon]
                                            WHERE [IconId] IN (SELECT [Id] FROM OPENJSON(@filters)WITH([Id] NVARCHAR(255))))
                                    END)
```

If I delete CASE statement and put only the SELECT in the IN the query works. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR instead of case _expressions_ in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Please provide your json present on @filters variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use regular boolean logic:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [PointOfInterest]
WHERE @filters IS NULL OR
      [PointOfInterest].[Id] IN (SELECT poi.[PointOfInterestId]
                                 FROM [PointOfInterestIcon] poi
                                 WHERE poiIconId IN (SELECT [Id] FROM OPENJSON(@filters) WITH ([Id] NVARCHAR(255)))
                                );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a inner select that return  more then a row .. you colud  use TOP 1 for limit this result

```
SELECT * 
FROM [PointOfInterest]
WHERE [PointOfInterest].[Id] IN (
    CASE
            WHEN @filters IS NULL THEN [PointOfInterest].[Id]
            WHEN @filters IS NOT NULL THEN (
                    SELECT TOP 1 DISTINCT [PointOfInterestIcon].[PointOfInterestId]
                    FROM  [PointOfInterestIcon]
                    WHERE [IconId] IN (
                    SELECT [Id] FROM OPENJSON(@filters)WITH([Id] NVARCHAR(255))))
    END)
```